# Merge offline Windows updates

Tags: windows, windows-update

A long time ago, when Windows XP was mainstream, I heard a rumor that you could merge offline Windows updates by providing some sort of clever command keys. The rumor was quite technical and resided on the fact(?) that a Windows update is, essentially, a database for Windows Installer, and therefore, it is feasible to merge several databases, resulting in a database, installing which would have the same effect as installing the original update files one by one.

I wonder, was that rumor actually correct? Can one actually merge several Windows offline updates into one big file?

Side note: Found [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/115779/offline-windows-updates) ("Offline Windows updates"), but it's not really what I want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [WSUS Offline Update](http://www.wsusoffline.net/).  It's a program that does just that, free and readily available.